How to Ignore SSL Certificate Error in cURL for Microsoft Graph API during Development Phase?
I’m working on a PHP script to interact with the Microsoft Graph API. Here’s my code:
function SendGraphEmail() {

    $tokenRequestContext = new ClientCredentialContext(
        'tenantId',
        'clientId',
        'clientSecret'
    );

    // With specific scopes
    $scopes = [
        'User.Read',
        'Mail.Send',
        'Mail.ReadWrite'
    ];
    $graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);

    try {
        $user = $graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId('[userPrincipalName]')->get()->wait();
        echo "Hello, I am {$user->getGivenName()}";
    
    } catch (ApiException $ex) {
        error_log('error');
        echo 'error';
    }
}

When I run this code, I encounter the following error:
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
I understand that this error is related to SSL verification, which is important for production security. However, during the development phase, I need to bypass SSL certificate verification to test the functionality.
How can I configure this to ignore SSL verification temporarily, just for development purposes?
Notes:

I am using PHP and a library for Microsoft Graph API.
I’m aware of the security implications and will re-enable SSL verification for production.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Is the GraphServiceClient class your own? Or from a library?

@maiorano84 The GraphServiceClient class is from the Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP. I got the source code from Packagist here: https://packagist.org/packages/microsoft/microsoft-graph

You should not disable the certificate verification, you should fix the root certs in your dev/test environment so that the certificate validates correctly.

You can also avoid having to hardcode your Azure credentials into the function by instantiating the ClientCredentialContext and/or GraphServiceClient objects outside of the function and passing it in via function argument, eg: function SendGraphEmail($graphServiceClient) {...}, which also enables you to use it across multiple calls without reinstantiating.

This question is similar to: cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
